# Bootcamp (and laptop) freeze during partition on High Sierra

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, high-sierra

I don't know if this is a problem specific to Windows 10 (which I'm trying to install), or High Sierra, but here it goes.

I am trying to install Windows 10 Anniversary Edition on a Macbook Air (early 2015) which is running High Sierra (10.13). I first freed up around 40 GB, which meant that I had 65 GB free, which was more than sufficient for Bootcamp.

Bootcamp runs, downloads the Windows support software, and says it's partitioning. Now, the problem is, the Bootcamp disappears while partitioning, and the system hangs completely. Only the cursor works. I can't even change the brightness. When I hard reboot, the system functions as normal, but in the Disk Utility, no space has even been allocated.

Looking around on the Web and here, the same problem has been reported by a ton of people, but all of the answers are outdated, dating back to the age of Mountain Lion and Snow Leopard - "simply partition a volume named BOOTCAMP of size 35-40 GB", which simply doesn't work here.

If anybody could guide me towards setting up Windows, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out.

Asked the same question on Apple Communities, got an answer saying

> Hi, 
>   Bootcamp is not compatible (yet) with the new APFS shipped with High Sierra.

Which (probably) means that I'll have to wait for a new software update.